# How can I make a simplexml_load_file readable?

Tags: php, xml

Hello everyone I'm using simplexml_load_file to load a url so I can get a catalog from a another company. How can I make it so its readable like this:

Catalog website
[image]

and not like this

Catalog in php

[image]

The catalog that's on the website is the url that I use in my code, so e.g. `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@WEBSITE.com/generator/catalog/xml` - I can't share the company's real address.

this is how I get the catalog from the company

```
$url = "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@WEBSITE.com/generator/catalog/xml";
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
   foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $product) {
   print_r($product);
}
```

Comment: [You already asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949527/how-can-i-get-an-external-catalog-by-running-a-url) but for some reason you have deleted the question, including the comments that were trying to help you, and have re-asked it with less information about the problem. That isn't a good way to get a good answer.

Comment: @Quentin yeah because its a different question then the previous one.... I have the data I just need to make it look good and my previous question was about how I could show the data on screen and I have that

Comment: Oh. Then you seem to need an introductory guide to HTML and an introductory guide to CSS along with a UI design course. That's too broad a topic for SO.

Comment: Or, looking at the pictures, it's possible that what you're really asking for is a method to "pretty print" an XML document.

Comment: Your first screenshot looks very like the browser's default display of an XML document. You don't need to do *anything* to get that, just echo the XML to the browser with the appropriate Content-Type header. If you want to generate an HTML page (or some other format) that shows the *contents* of the XML, then as ADyson says, searching for "pretty-print" is probably a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```php
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->saveXML();
```

and then for viewing:

```php
echo '<pre>'. print_r($product, true). '</pre>';
```

You should also be careful with simplexml_load_file(), since it can be affected by https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62577. Instead you can use `simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($filepath));`

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Firstly, `preserveWhiteSpace`, `formatOutput`, and `saveXML` are part of [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/DOMDocument) not [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/SimpleXMLElement); you can [convert between the two](https://www.php.net/dom_import_simplexml), but you don't mention doing that. Secondly, if you did use the first piece of code, the result of `$xml->saveXML();` would be a string, so there would be no need for `print_r`; and it would be the whole document by default, not equivalent to `$product` in the question.